# Add custom S3 endpoint for Vertica backup

Tags: amazon-s3, vertica

I am trying to backup the Vertica cluster to a S3 like data store (supports S3 protocol) internal to my enterprise network. We have similar credentials (ACCESS KEY and SECRET KEY).
Here's how my .ini file looks like

```
[S3]
s3_backup_path = s3://vertica_backups
s3_backup_file_system_path = []:/vertica/backups
s3_concurrency_backup = 10
s3_concurrency_restore = 10

[Transmission]
hardLinkLocal = True

[Database]
dbName = production
dbUser = dbadmin
dbPromptForPassword = False

[Misc]
snapshotName = fullbak1
restorePointLimit = 3
objectRestoreMode = createOrReplace
passwordFile = pwdfile
enableFreeSpaceCheck = True
```

Where can I supply my specific endpoint? For instance, my S3 store is available on `a.b.c.d:80`. I have tried changing `s3_backup_path = a.b.c.d:80://wms_vertica_backups` but I get the error `Error: Error in VBR config: Invalid s3_backup_path`. Also, I have the ACCESS KEY and SECRET KEY in `~/.aws/credentials`.

After going through more resources I have exported the following ENV variables VBR_BACKUP_STORAGE_ENDPOINT_URL, VBR_BACKUP_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY_ID, VBR_BACKUP_STORAGE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY. `vbr` init throws the error `Error: Unable to locate credentials Init FAILED.` , I'm guessing it is still trying to connect to the AWS S3 servers. (Now removed credentials from `~/.aws/credentials`

I think it's worthy to add that I'm running Vertica Enterprise mode 8.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for something similar, the question was answered in the Vertica forum [here](https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/241580/specify-custom-s3-endpoint-for-backup/p1?new=1)